# Having problems loading net/ssh/shell

Tags: ruby, shell, ssh, jenkins

I have a jenkins job that right now is just trying to run a simple ruby script. However it is failing at require 'net/ssh/shell
In Jenkins I have:

```
gem install net-ssh -v 2.0
gem install net-ssh-shell
gem uninstall net-ssh --version 2.1.4
```

In ruby I have

```
gem 'net-ssh', '=2.0.0'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/shell'
```

But when I run the script I get this error:

```
Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate net-ssh-shell-0.2.0, because net-ssh-2.0.0 conflicts with net-ssh (~> 2.1.0)
  raise_if_conflicts at /usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/specification.rb:1637
            activate at /usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/specification.rb:746
        try_activate at /usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems.rb:212
             require at /usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59
             require at /usr/local/rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55
              (root) at sparse_databases/refresh_sparse.rb:4
```

I have tried not specifying which version of net-ssh to install, not uninstalling 2.1.4.

Comment: you might as well use `bundler` to install the scripts dependencies

Comment: just use `gem 'net-ssh', '2.0.0'`, avoiding the `=` sign. Use it not in your app, but in **Gemfile**, and you bunlder to meet the requirements.

Comment: Using a gemefile for this is not ideal. This script is in a 'tools' repo that has many different scripts with potentially conflicting requirements. This is the first case where we actually care about the version (this code will never be run on production) and a way to set the version on a job/script level is much preferred.